# Defining an ID number once and using it every file path

Tags: python, filenames, filepath

I have a bunch of file paths:

```
shapefile = "C:\\file\\path \\here\\this\\one\\is\\different\\2001_6W.shp"
place1 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place1_2001.shp"
place2 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place2_2001.shp"
place3 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place3_2001.shp"
```

I would like it if I could define the number ID (2001) and then have it be used in the file name, like this:

```
ID = 2001

shapefile = "C:\\file\\path \\here\\this\\one\\is\\different\\ID_6W.shp"
place1 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place1_ID.shp"
place2 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place2_ID.shp"
place3 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place3_ID.shp
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm not sure if I explained what I want very well.

Comment: You can use regular expression for this - but why would you want to? Why don't you just append the string like "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place1_"+ID+".shp"?

Answer (score 3):

You should use string formatting, like so:

```
ID = 2001
# Positionally replace {}
place1 = "c:\\file\\path\\here\\place1_{}.shp".format(ID)
# It also works with keywords!
place2 = "c:\\file\\path\\here\\place2_{id}.shp".format(id=ID)
```

This lets it be type-ambiguous, in case you want to use an integer sometimes or a string other times. It also can handle as many pieces as you want, so you could loop like;

```
ID = 2001

places = {}
for place_number in range(10):
    places[place_number] = "c:\\file\\path\\here\\place{}_{}.shp".format(place_number, ID)
    # OR #
    places[place_number] = "c:\\file\\path\\here\\place{place}_{id}.shp".format(place=place_number, id=ID)
```

EDIT: There's more to string formatting, see the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for more.

Comment: Thank you for actually getting the string formatting version correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID = "2001"

place1 = "C:\\file\\path\\here\\place1_" + ID + ".shp"
```

Notice the quotes around the ID value "2001", that makes it a string, which allows you to add it to other strings.  Otherwise you'd end up with a TypeError which will arise when you try to add integers to strings.